# Steam market API price list for a specific APP

Tags: php, json, api, steam

I'm playing with the 
Steam Web API right now. And I need to grab a price list of the cheapest market listings of the game/app PUBG [(http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080)](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=578080)

I know that it's possible to see the cheapest listing for each item, but would it be possible somehow to grab the cheapest price of all the different items?

I know that [Steamapi.io](http://Steamapi.io) is making this possible, but the prices are not really stable.